# What paint-brush-like font does Night Club use for their logo?

Tags: font-identification

I am trying to identify the font in the logo for [Night Club](http://nightclubband.com/):

[image: Night Club logo]

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the era of this? If it's pre mid-80s, it may be hand lettered. If later, it very well could be a font. I'd search MyFonts for 'brush' and 'hand lettering'

Comment: @DA01 if you will see the source posting, probably, you will agree that this post was actually a spamming attempt.

Comment: new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ You can upload a pic of the font or the actual website its on.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you can find the exact font, but [this one](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/comicraft/tim-sale-brush/brush-italic/glyphs.html) looks similar -

[image]

or [this one](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/cyberian-khatru/brush-with-death/):

[image]

Answer (score -2):

[image]did u find it???... check this 1 https://www.dafont.com/them.font  if u've finally found the 1 u were looking 4 please share...
 Best Regards